# Some questions with Python codes in simulating oil-paint

Tags: python, numpy

In the process of simulating oil-paint.

```
    #first, generate xslope and yslope
    gby,gbx = np.mgrid[0:brush_image.shape[0],0:brush_image.shape[1]]
    gbx = gbx / float(brush_image.shape[1]) -.5
    gby = gby / float(brush_image.shape[0]) -.5
    dgx,dgy = rn()-.5,rn()-.5
    #then mix the slopes according to angle
    gbmix = gbx * math.cos(angle/180.*math.pi+dgx) - gby * math.sin(angle/180.*math.pi+dgx)
```

where `rn()` is a random function which produces the number of [0,1] brush_image is 2-d array. the angle is the degree.

I don't know the `gbmix` used to be in oil-paint. The formula is followed

```
gbx * math.cos(angle/180.*math.pi+dgx) - gby * math.sin(angle/180.*math.pi+dgx)
```

I don't know what the commentary is mean. It might be related to simple motion blur accroding to the rest of code. what theory does the formula based on?

append similar code

```
def generate_motion_blur_kernel(dim=3,angle=0.,threshold_factor=1.3,divide_by_dim=True):
    radian = angle/360*math.pi*2 + math.pi/2
    # perpendicular
    # x2,y2 = math.cos(radian),math.sin(radian)
    # the directional vector

    # first, generate xslope and yslope
    gby,gbx = np.mgrid[0:dim,0:dim]
    cen = (dim+1)/2-1
    gbx = gbx - float(cen)
    gby = gby - float(cen)
    # gbx = gbx / float(cen) -.5
    # gby = gby / float(cen) -.5

    # then mix the slopes according to angle
    gbmix = gbx * math.cos(radian) - gby * math.sin(radian)

    kernel = (threshold_factor - gbmix*gbmix).clip(min=0.,max=1.)

    if divide_by_dim:
        kernel /= dim * dim * np.mean(kernel)
    else:
        pass

    return kernel.astype('float32')
```

Comment: It may help if you add where this code comes from, and where that result `gbmix` gets used. Is it simply a deformation of the brush shape?

Comment: Maybe. I will show briefly code since the source code project is too big. I guess this code simulate the brush motion.But I do't know why it does work. PLZ give some advice to me.Thank you